# Versão do ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Boa tarde,

Estou iniciando com o DotNet Core, e ao eu criar meu primeiro projeto escolhendo a opção "**Aplicativo Web ASP.NET Core(.NET Core)**" na próxima tela me aparece apenas as versões abaixo

1. ASP.NET Core 1.0
2. ASP.NET Core 1.1

Porem eu já instalei o SDK (dotnet-sdk-2.1.402-win-x64), mas essa versão 2.1 não aparece para eu escolher, segue imagem para melhor visualização.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entrando no prompt a versão aparentemente está instalada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe como resolver ?

Answer (score 0):

Certifique-se de está usando o Visual Studio 2017 Update 3 (versão 15.3)

> Para verificar sua versão do Visual Studio 2017:
>   No menu Ajuda, escolha Sobre o Microsoft Visual Studio.
>   Na caixa de diálogo Sobre o Microsoft Visual Studio, verifique o
>   número da versão.
>
> - Para aplicativos .NET .NET 2.2 Preview 1, versão 15.9 do Visual    Studio 2017 (atualmente em Preview) ou superior.
> - Para aplicativos .NET Core 2.1, o Visual Studio 2017 versão 15.7 ou    superior.
> - Para aplicativos .NET Core 2.0, o Visual Studio 2017 versão 15.3 ou    superior.
> - Para aplicativos .NET Core 1.x, o Visual Studio 2017 versão 15.0 ou    superior.

Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore21#prerequisites-with-visual-studio-2017